# Update Relay Store from data saved on cache for Offline mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, relayjs

I'm developing a React native app, and want to restore data saved on cache when the user opens the app again, but it's offline.
I was able to get the latest store by using `store.getSource()` and save it as a serialised JSON to the device storage. I do also recover and unserialise it, but when I set the value on the record source and publish to the store:

```js
recordSource.set('client:root', record['client:root'])
store.publish(recordSource);
```

It seems Relay doesn't uses this to resolve the queries:

```js
loadQuery({}, { fetchPolicy: 'store-or-network' });
```

When offline it will throw the error as the query returned no response. Anyone know what I missing here?

Comment: tried react-relay-offline ?

Comment: I'm on a quite limited environment, is very strict what we can use and install. For now I solved by not trying to extend but intercepting calls on the Network layer and returning the cached response